# Is every Pisot-like integer the product of a Pisot integer and a root of unity?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, absolute-value

For lack of better terminology, let's call an algebraic integer $\beta$ *Pisot-like* if $|\beta|_{\mathbf{v}} > 1$ for the place $\mathbf{v}$ of $\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$ corresponding to the embedding $\beta \mapsto \beta$ and $|\beta|_v < 1$ for every other infinite place of $\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$.

With this in mind, a Pisot integer (or Pisot number, if you prefer) is a Pisot-like positive real algebraic integer.

**Question:** Is every Pisot-like integer the product of a Pisot integer and a root of unity?

---

*What I have so far:*

Clearly, if $\beta$ is Pisot-like and $\zeta$ is a root of unity, then $\zeta\beta$ is Pisot-like because $|\cdot|_v$ is multiplicative for every place $v$ of $\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$.

On the other hand, for any Pisot-like number we can find a rotation of the complex plane which sends it to a real positive Pisot-like number. This would be enough to conclude if I knew, for example, that every rotation of the complex plane which preserves integrality can be written as the product by a root of unity.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Of course you are right. I actually thought about this in terms of equivalence classes of absolute values. The edited question should be more precise.

Comment: A.P.: yeah, I realized that it wouldn't preserve integrality and deleted my comment. (In fact, it clearly doesn't: it sends $1$ to $\frac{3+4i}{5}$, which obviously isn't integral).

Comment: I'm looking for a counterexample with the following idea. Take a Pisot cubic, like roots of $p(x)=x^3+nx^2-1$ for a large enough $n$. Disturb that somewhat and look at the zeros of
$$q(x)=(x^3+nx^2-1)^2+1$$
instead. They obviously come in complex conjugate pairs. Because they are "close" to zeros of $p(x)$, we have a chance of controlling their absolute values. Still need to think of a way of dealing with the roots of unity...

Comment: Or may be use a quadratic in place of $p(x)$? Can we see that the argument of the integer $\beta=(3+\sqrt{5+4i})/2$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$? The conjugates are $(3\pm\sqrt{5\pm4i})/2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have no idea... just for fun I tried [plugging it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+%28argument+of+%28%283+%2B+sqrt%285+%2B+4i%29%29%2F2%29%29%2Fpi+rational%3F) into WolframAlpha, but it didn't spit out anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are counterexamples of higher degrees as well. I post my argument, because some of the ideas may be reusable.

Consider the polynomial
$$
q(x)=(x^2-4x-1)^2+1.
$$
By Eisenstein's criterion ($p=2$) $q(x)$ is irreducible.
Its zeros are zeros of either of $x^2-4x-(1\pm i)$, so they are
$$
u_1=2+\sqrt{5+i},\ u_2=2+\sqrt{5-i},\ u_3=2-\sqrt{5+i},\ u_4=2-\sqrt{5-i}.
$$

Let $L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{5+i},\sqrt{5-i})$ be the splitting field of $q(x)$. Because $5+i=(1+i)(3-2i)$ (resp. $5-i=(1-i)(3+2i)$ it is easy to show that the extension $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{5+i})/\Bbb{Q}(i)$ ramifies above the prime $3+2i$ (resp. the extension $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{5-i})/\Bbb{Q}(i)$ ramifies above the prime $3-2i$) but does not ramify above the conjugate prime, so these two extensions are distinct. Therefore $[L:\Bbb{Q}]=8$.

Let us view the Galois group $G=Gal(L/\Bbb{Q})$ as a subgroup of $S_4$ (use the subscripts of the roots). We see that there are automorphisms $\sigma_1=(24)$ and $\sigma_2=(13)$ in $G$, because these are the automorphism of $L$ over $\Bbb{Q}(i)$. Furthermore, the complex conjugation acts as $\sigma_3=(12)(34)$. The group they generate is a copy of the dihedral group $D_4$ of eight elements.

For the purposes of the problem at hand we specify that $\sqrt{5\pm i}$ are the complex numbers with arguments $\pm\dfrac12\arctan\dfrac15$. This means that
$|u_1|=|u_2|>4$ and $|u_3|=|u_4|<1$, so we have a Pisot situation.

I claim that no power of $u_1^k$, $k$ a positive integer, is a real number. This is equivalent to saying that $u_1$ cannot be gotten from a real algebraic integer by multiplying it with a root of unity.

One of the keys comes from Galois theory. The subfield $L\cap\Bbb{R}$ corresponds to the group $\langle \sigma_3\rangle\le G$. OTOH the subfield
$\Bbb{Q}(u_1)$ corresponds to the group $\langle \sigma_1\rangle\le G$. But the subgroup corresponding to $\Bbb{Q}(u_1)\cap \Bbb{R}$ is
$$
\langle\sigma_1,\sigma_3\rangle=\langle(24),(12)(34)\rangle=D_4
$$
all of $G$, so we get that $\Bbb{Q}(u_1)\cap\Bbb{R}=\Bbb{Q}$. So if $u_1^k$ is a real number for some $k$, then $u_1^k$ needs to be rational (because it is in that intersection of fields). Furthermore, $u_1^k$ is an algebraic integer, so it needs to be a rational integer as well.

But if $u_1^k=m\in\Bbb{Z}$, then an application of a suitable element of $G$ implies that $u_3^k=m$ also. But $0<|u_3|^k<1$, so this is absurd.

Comment: Thanks, this is a neat argument! Also, I don't really like accepting my own answers, and I did enough of that already...

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I fixed the notation of your last paragraph ($\sigma_1$ suddenly became $\sigma_2$). I also have a small question: how do you draw conclusions on $|u_i|$ from the argument $\theta$ of $\sqrt{5 \pm i}$? I assume that it is because $\theta$ small implies that $\text{Re}(\sqrt{5 \pm i}) \approx \sqrt{5}$; is this correct?

Comment: Correct, @A.P.  And thanks for spotting the error!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a counterexample. Consider $\beta \in \Bbb{Z}[i] \setminus \Bbb{Z}$. Then $\Bbb{Q}(\beta) = \Bbb{Q}(i)$ has exactly one archimedean place, because it is a purely complex extension of degree $2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. Hence $\beta$ is Pisot-like iff $|\beta| > 1$, where $|\cdot|$ is the usual absolute value on $\Bbb{C}$, which happens iff $\beta \neq \pm i$.

Finally, note that $|\beta|$ is always an alegbraic integer; if it is not Pisot, then $\beta$ cannot be obtained from a Pisot integer through any rotation of the complex plane. One such $\beta$ is $1+i$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, I think I found a simpler counterexample. If this is indeed correct, then my hypothesis was fundamentally flawed...